# SQL query to get the start and end date from tasks labeled 'D' if they exist, and the minimum start and end date otherwise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query my data so that it obtains the start and end date for each job and cost code. I want one start and end date for each JobNumber and CostCode. If one of the rows contains a Status of 'D' then I would like that StartDate and EndDate to be the final StartDate and EndDate for that JobNumber and CostCode. If a JobNumber and CostCode combination does not contain a Status of 'D' then I would just like to return the minimum StartDate and EndDate of all instances of the JobNumber and CostCode.

The data is grouped by JobNumber, CostCode, and Status so there are no duplicates of these three columns. Additionally only the 'D' Status rows will contain an EndDate so the resultant EndDate should always be the 'D' row or Null.
The table looks like this:

| JobNumber | CostCode | Status | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 566169 | 053800 | D | 2021-10-08 00:00:00.000 | 2021-10-18 14:01:55.517 |
| 566170 | 010800 | D | 2022-05-18 00:00:00.000 | 2022-05-22 15:38:58.447 |
| 566170 | 010800 | B | 2022-04-04 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 566170 | 026200 | B | 2022-04-21 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 566170 | 026200 | A | 2022-05-06 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 566175 | 033500 | A | NULL | NULL |

And the result should look like this:

| JobNumber | CostCode | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 566169 | 053800 | 2021-10-08 00:00:00.000 | 2021-10-18 14:01:55.517 |
| 566170 | 010800 | 2022-05-18 00:00:00.000 | 2022-05-22 15:38:58.447 |
| 566170 | 026200 | 2022-04-21 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 566175 | 033500 | NULL | NULL |

I have been stuck on this a while and am not very experienced with SQL so am having trouble. I have attempted joining it to itself and CASE statements with a GROUP BY on JobNumber and CostCode but have had no luck either way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question but let me try to explain. In an example like rows 4 and 5 I would want it to return the minimum start date. One thing I forgot to include is that only the 'D' Status rows will have an EndDate. I will edit my question to include this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT JobNumber, CostCode, Status, StartDate, EndDate
FROM (
    SELECT JobNumber, CostCode, Status, StartDate, EndDate
        , row_number() over 
            (
                partition by JobNumber, CostCode 
                order by case when status='D' then 0 else 1 end, StartDate, EndDate
            ) rn
    FROM [table]
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

See it run here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75cfbf2f3519da7acc116fc8e6047f75

Comment: @austin The OP doesn't state that can ever be the case. It's ambiguous. Both descriptions fit what the OP has provided, without further details it's impossible to say which is more appropriate to the OP's true needs.

Comment: @Austin I did consider that, but in my experience mixing between rows like that is usually not the right result, so I chose this option. If he doesn't like how I defined the minimum row, we can adjust the `ORDER BY` for that. Otherwise we can try conditional aggregation.

Comment: Just talked myself through this query and I understand it now and it appears to be correct! I edited the question as the only EndDate's will be on tasks with Status = 'D' and I forgot to include that however I believe this query works with regard to that anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a cursor for each job. If there is a D record for that job then select that start and enddate, else select startdate and endate where the startdate is equal to the min start date for that job.

Comment: Definitely do not need a cursor for this.

Answer (score -1):

Use a traditional `UNION`. And `CONCAT` for SQL server .

```
SELECT
   jobNumber,
   costCode,
   max(startdate) as startdate,
   max(enddate) as enddate
from tablename
where status = 'D'
group by jobNumber, costcode
UNION
select
   jobnumber,
   costcode,
   min(startdate) as startdate,
   min(enddate) as enddate
from tablename
where CONCAT(jobNumber,':',costCode) not in (SELECT CONCAT(jobNumber,':',costCode) from tablename where status='D')
group by jobnumber, costcode
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=74c66b5467a40221fb79e15efdfcc61c)

Comment: Thanks for pointing those things out Mat. I've updated my answer.

Comment: What if the costcode exists for a different job?

Comment: Tricky tricky. We can concatenate (jobnumber, ':', costCode)` to create a unique ID.

Comment: The deleted answer here did that. Try `NOT EXISTS()` instead. Using `CONCAT()` in that way kneecaps the optimiser. *(My proposed revision to that deleted answer; https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1798e198aee9618a845de4ed6581f72)*